# Check whether the file is already exists Android not working

Tags: android

I want to check whether the file is already exists in Download folder in Android. I'm using Android download manager to download the file. In there  `if` section is not working. If file is already there (Ex: File name - songname.mp3), when downloading the same file for the second time it's downloading the file as `songname1.mp3`.  I have tried the code below. I want to show a message if the file is already there.

Please help me to fix this issue.

```
public void DownloadChecker() {
    File applictionFile =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ "/"+"mysongs.mp3");

    if(applictionFile.exists()) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Already Exists", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        String servicestring = Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE;
        DownloadManager downloadmanager;
        downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(servicestring);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(DownloadUrl);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this,
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"mysongs.mp3");

        Long reference = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added `storage read permission`?

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh- Yes. Already added the following permissions

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try changing:

```
File applictionFile =  new File(Environment.
        getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ "/"+"mysongs.mp3");
```

to:

```
File applictionFile =  new File(Environment.
        getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "mysongs.mp3");
```

Comment: You don't even need the "/" in the middle. Replace it with "," and the file name will be the second parameter. Just the way the OP's post shows in the `else` statement

Comment: Yes you can definitely choose to do that, but my aim is to show minimal change concentrating on the real issue, just to avoid any misconceptions to the reader.

Comment: Of course, I understand. I was just informing the OP. Didn't want to post a new answer for that minor change since I saw your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**change**

```
 if(applictionFile.exists()) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Already Exists", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**to**

```
if(applictionFile.canRead()) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Already Exists", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**or**

```
 if(applictionFile.isFile()) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Already Exists", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Emdad Hossain

Answer (score 2):

Try in simple way

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // do your code stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

on which testing device are you testing your app? is it above api-23 then you should have to set permission at the run time ! or else try this

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/mysongs.mp3");

if(myFile.exists()){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Already Exists", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Radhey